# Where is Map [] operator defined in Dart?

Tags: dictionary, flutter, dart

I have checked these files. However, I am not sure how `Map`'s `[]` operator is defined (excluding `_UnmodifiableMapMixin` in collection/maps.dart because it is not `Map` used normally). 
Could you give me an idea where `[]` is defined?

- [core/maps.dart](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/blob/master/sdk/lib/core/map.dart) --> I found `V operator [](Object key);` but this does not have an actual content.
- [collection/maps.dart](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/blob/master/sdk/lib/collection/maps.dart) --> This file only calls `V operator [](Object key) => _map[key];` and I am not sure where `_map[key]` is actually defined.
- [collection/linked_hash_map.dart](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/blob/master/sdk/lib/collection/linked_hash_map.dart) --> I couldn't find `operator []`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you tagged this question with `flutter`, I'm assuming you're asking about the implementation when running with the Dart VM/runtime.

`Map` is an abstract class with a factory constructor that instantiates some internal, concrete class.  You can figure out exactly what it is by running:

```dart
void main() {
  print('${Map().runtimeType}');
}
```

With the Dart VM, this will print out `_InternalLinkedHashMap<dynamic, dynamic>`. (With DartPad, it prints `JsLinkedHashMap<dynamic, dynamic>`.)

From there you can find the [`_InternalLinkedHashMap` implementation](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/blob/4aa896464a4860f2e8e35c9f31b4742aa3ed3dc1/sdk/lib/_internal/vm/lib/compact_hash.dart#L152) and the [`operator []` implementation](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/blob/4aa896464a4860f2e8e35c9f31b4742aa3ed3dc1/sdk/lib/_internal/vm/lib/compact_hash.dart#L359) it gets from `_LinkedHashMapMixin`.